# I am getting error while trying to connect to cpanel mysql database through c# application

Tags: c#, mysql, cpanel, remote-access

Facing trouble while connecting to cpanel database from c# desktop application. Walked through hundreds of tutorial but still no success. Added % to the host list of cpanel but still no success. Please guide me what wrong i am doing.

The error:

> "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

The code:

```
string constring = "SERVER=198.49.72.34;PORT=3306;DATABASE=e_hearing;Uid=district_courts;Pwd=*googleisgood#";
try
{
    MySqlConnection con;
    con = new MySqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = constring;
    //con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ToString();
    con.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("success");
}
catch(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to walk through hundreds of tutorials, you'll just have to read the error and fix the issue described therein.

Comment: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts, Sir this is the error i have already pasted it on the top of code

Comment: Firewall rules? Other limitations? Check with the MySQL command-line tool or Workbench application before presuming it's a code problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster i tried to figure out but failed.

Answer (score 1):

First eliminate any possibility of a network issue by using Telnet to connect to the TCP address and Port, as described here http://blog.industrialnetworking.com/2011/09/using-telnet-to-test-open-ports.html

Second eliminate any coding errors by moving the database to the workstation machine, and replacing the IP address with localhost. Since you will always be able to talk to your local host TCP address, this will eliminate any network issues.