# unable to connect to a specific host in case of cpanel but work perfect on localhost

Tags: c#, mysql

unable to connect to a specific host in case of cpanel but work perfect on localhost in c# application . my connection string is  . 
give the error "unable to connect to a specific host"

```
string server = "abc.com";
string database = "abc";
string user = "abc";
string password = "abc";
string port = "3306";
string sslM = "none"; 

string connectionString = String.Format("server={0};port={1};user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}; SslMode={5}", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting error while trying to connect to cpanel mysql database through c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602849/i-am-getting-error-while-trying-to-connect-to-cpanel-mysql-database-through-c-sh)

Comment: @pstrjds all prior commenters have write access to such mod moved-to-chat rooms. See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/181442?tab=access